# Sqlite Online Backup Using System.Data.Sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

How can a sqlite database be backed up in native C# code while the database is still online? All of the [online backup api](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/backup_finish.html) examples are in C code.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The online backup API was added to `System.Data.Sqlite` in [version 1.0.80.0 - April 1, 2012](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki). You can create a database backup while there are other external connections like so

```
using(var source = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ActiveDb.db; Version=3;"))
using(var destination = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BackupDb.db; Version=3;"))
{
    source.Open();
    destination.Open();
    source.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
}
```

Also, `BackupDb.db` will be created if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Your example is right, but I just want to remark that the transactions of both databases must be closed, otherwise you'll get a "unknown error" by sqLite!

Comment: I believe the "using" keyword takes care of closing the connections automatically.