# Backup SQLite database with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I don't find documentation for VB.NET

Trying to adapt the code of the answer on [Sqlite Online Backup Using System.Data.Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129531/sqlite-online-backup-using-system-data-sqlite)

The code from @Elias is:

```
using(var source = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ActiveDb.db; Version=3;"))
using(var destination = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BackupDb.db; Version=3;"))
{
source.Open();
destination.Open();
source.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
}
```

and my code looks like:

```
Dim conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyBase.sqlite;Version=3;Password=myPassword;foreign keys=true")

Dim connbackup = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyBaseBackup.sqlite; Version=3;Password=myPassword;foreign keys=true")

    Try
        Using (conn)

            conn.Open()
            connbackup.Open()

            conn.BackupDatabase(connbackup, "main", "main", -1, null, 0)

        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
```

Visual Studio marks on red "Null" is not declared and I don´t have any clue about how to solve the error. I think is the "callback" what is wrong

[image]

Comment: In VB null is `Nothing`.  Also, connections are one of those things that should be disposed of when you are done with it.  That is why the c# version has both wrapped in `Using` / `using` blocks

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, I posted the working solution with double Try - Using blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the direct translation of that C# code:

```
Using source As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=ActiveDb.db; Version=3;"),
      destination As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=BackupDb.db; Version=3;")
    source.Open()
    destination.Open()
    source.BackupDatabase(destination, "main", "main", -1, Nothing, 0)
End Using
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work. Something wrong with the sintaxis. I will post the solution.

Comment: @fedeteka the only thing wrong is an extra trailing parens (edit: *was* wrong)

Comment: @Plutonix. Right, thanks. Also I think Version=3;" works the same as Version=3" without the last semicolon

Comment: there are a number of other cool things you can add to the connection string, so it can be a good idea to leave the trailing delimiter