# How to dispose a PdfWriter or FileStream object?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

My program use SQlite and iTextsharp.

One button allow the user to create and display a PDF inside a WebBrowser. It works fine the first time, and sometimes more than once, but after a few clicks (every one generating a new version of the PDF with different fonts, sizes...) I get a exception saying the file PDF is allready open.
After the exception the program keep running.

I tried with pauses after the click or checking if the file was already open and force the close (The "IsFileOpen" function of this post [How to check if the text file is open and close the text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706312/how-to-check-if-the-text-file-is-open-and-close-the-text-file) ), garbage collector, but still the same.

The code looks like this:

```
Try
    Using (conn)
        conn.Open()

            Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream(MyPDFFile, FileMode.Create))

            pdfDoc.Open()

                'All the code to create the PDF

            pdfDoc.Close()

    End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    'The code to show the exception
End Try
```

The Debug always point to the line "Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter", meaning the pdfDOC is still open when the program reaches that line after a few clicks

Sometimes Adobe Reader say error 523:523 but the solution https://forums.adobe.com/thread/961724 " Is the protected mode enabled (Preferences > General > Enable Protected Mode at startup)?" didn't fix the problem

**how can I fix that exception?**

Comment: Everything/anything that exposes a Dispose method ought t be used in a `Using` block to close and dispose of it.  I dont know about the PDFWriter but you arent saving the stream to be able to dispose of it

Comment: If I understand you say I need to use another Using before the "Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter" line?

Comment: Yes, use it to create the FileStream, the existing  `Using` on the conn object wont actually do anything since it is created elsewhere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604859/backup-sqlite-database-with-vb-net#comment66540616_39613794

Comment: Not familiar with iTextSharp, but you could try assigning the `FileStream` to a variable and disposing it.

Comment: @sss Thanks. I test with code like `Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream = File.Create(MyPDFFile)`
`Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs)` and at the end `fs.dispose()` but still not working

Comment: *"I get a exception saying the file PDF is allready open"* - is the PDF probably still open in the web browser?

Comment: @mkl Thanks but no because I close the webbrowser and wait until is ready. Now I test the program using FoxitReader as default PDF reader and is working fine, maybe is something about Adobe Reader and security

Comment: After reading a lot of post about WebBrowsers troubles I solved this situation using AxAcroPDF instead of WebBrowser. Thanks